# Why Connection is Failing when call REST API end point from android app from emulator

Tags: android, rest, flask, post, okhttp

I am following [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/uploading-images-from-android-to-a-python-based-flask-server-691e4092a95e) tutorial for calling post function from andrioa app. Server is created on flask. Don't know error is comming.

I have tried http//127.0.0.1:5000 for running app on emulator, and tried http//[My IP Address]:5000 to run android app on my device. But each time connection failure.

I debug my project OnFailure() callback get called

Any suggestion will be helpful!!

My Android MainActivity.java

```
package com.asad.testrest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText ipv4AddressView = findViewById(R.id.IPAddress);
                String ipv4Address = ipv4AddressView.getText().toString();
                EditText portNumberView = findViewById(R.id.portNumber);
                String portNumber = portNumberView.getText().toString();

                String postUrl= "http://"+ipv4Address+":"+portNumber+"/";

                String postBodyText="Hello";
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                RequestBody postBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, postBodyText);

                postRequest(postUrl, postBody);
            }
        });
    }

    void postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();

                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        responseText.setText("Failed to Connect to Server");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        try {
                            responseText.setText(response.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my Python file is

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_request():
    return "Flask Server & Android are Working Successfully"

app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last I Solved my Problem. But using a technology service that is ngrok. I suggest everyone facing a problem similar to this must try ngrok

At least watch one video and consult from its documentation it is very easy!!!! believe me.....

Answer (score 0):

Which machine is running the flask code?
You need to set it up so the emulator can access the network, and also the server machine.

The emulator should be able to see the server host's IP and connect to it. Depending on your network and where the flask is actually running, you might need to forward ports or allow a connection through the host firewall.

Did you get to this paragraph in the tutorial?

> To determine the current IPv4 address, issue the ipconfig command (from Windows), as shown below. The IPv4 address is 192.168.16.110. It’s very important to make sure that both the Android phone and the development PC are connected to the same network because we’re using local IPv4 addresses. If they are connected to different networks, then the experiment will fail.

Try pinging your server from the emulator. If you get no response, your connection isn't configured properly.